# Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio 4.1. For some reason, it is failing to run my project. Below is the error I am getting. (I'm not even sure as to why it's asking me for the Twitter SDK, yet I don't use it anywhere in my app.)

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.2.0/twitter-2.2.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.2.0/twitter-2.2.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.2.0/twitter-2.2.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1 > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.1

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript 
{

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}


allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you include your app's `build.gradle` file as well? (As in the `build.gradle` file located in the `app` folder) You also seem to be using an extremely outdated version of the [FirebaseUI for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) library - the latest version available is 7.1.1.

Comment: Here is the Link to the build.gradle file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p2PaZp4YX70CpinWkG5QXArpULhIvWw5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the instructions in the link below to configure the Twitter Sign-in, The project runs fine now. But I can't fathom why it had to force me to use Twitter.
I also updated my Firebase UIto 7.1.1

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui